# Can you import a bitbucket project using the GitLab API?

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I am looking for a way to directly import a project from bitbucket using the Python GitLab API. I know that this can be done for Github projects (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/import.html), however I can't seem to find a way to do this for bitbucket. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/bitbucket.html

Comment: @SmbatPogosyan Thanks, I have read that but I need to be able to do this using the Gitlab API not the UI